# may akka use multicast addreses?

Tags: scala, akka

There is simple actor API like actorRef ! Message

Sometimes I need to pass same message to a set of actors. Is there any way better way than enlist it some collection to iterate over with unicast?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your message is immutable, then just create it, then send it to multiple recipients.
Also, for Akka 2.0 you can use path selectors to do exactly that under the hood: [actorSelection](http://akka.io/docs/akka/2.0-M2/general/addressing.html#querying-the-logical-actor-hierarchy)

Comment: This is true, but you first need valid Actors to be known to your ActorSystem.  What if I needed to send messages to "whoever is listening" via multicast on my subnet?

Comment: Use system.eventStream and have your listeners subscribe to that.

Comment: eventStream is bound to some actorsystem. What if you want to have exactly the same mechanism as in udp multicast? I mean having a sender which has actorSelection  with multicast address as destination and receivers also bind to that adrress to listen for messages?

Answer (score 0):

That is indeed the way to do it.